What features are included/missing from Debian Nouveau drivers for NVIDIA GPU?
After breaking my setup for the 9999999^10th time with Nvidia Firmware & Drivers, I just did:
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt purge cuda*

Now my system boots faster and I really can't tell the difference between the default Debian Sid Nouveau and non-free nvidia drivers. Seems like they have a bad reputation to me, am I missing something.  Working perfect for me now.


I don't understand the question. Why would anything be bad about them?

I've been using NVIDIA "crap" binary drivers since 2000 or so and had exactly 0 (zero) breakages. If using them is such a pain for you, you could 1) dump Linux 2) buy an Intel/AMD GPU.

Possibly not in your case be we see significant performance differences between the nouveau and nvidia drivers. We're using the GPU for calculations, not video output, so this may account for the difference. Also, please don't post images of text.

You have a Nvidia RTX 3000 series card. That series is currently at about the sweet spot of Nouveau driver development: old enough to be well-known to developers, but new enough to be one of the most important targets of new development work.
Look at the Nouveau driver feature matrix: your card corresponds to the NV170 column. The only major features you are missing are:

hardware-assisted video decoding and playback (Xv, VDPAU, XvMC)
2d graphics acceleration features (which no modern desktop environment today uses anyway, because the 3d acceleration features are generally much more powerful)
dual-link DVI (does your card even have DVI anymore?)
SLI (also a very rare feature these days)
GPU computing features

So if you have plenty of CPU power for video decoding and don't care about GPU computing features, you basically have all the other features of your card supported.
Many older cards (NV140 and older) are more or less limited by missing GPU power management support, but that is not a problem for you.

Wow thanks!! Had no idea Noveau was part of freedesktop.org

The specs for nVidia cards, especially higher end cards, are not released.  Therefore, the open source Nouveau drivers can't support all features of all cards.
If you are not using all features, or the card you have is well supported by Nouveau, that driver may be fine for you.  If this wasn't the case, the driver would not be used at all.  Additionally, the driver is constantly improving and supporting more and more.
If you have a high end card, especially a card that can be used as a GPGPU, the Nouveau driver may not support necessary features like cuda, and the nVidia proprietary driver is required for full functionality.
Also, some cards are not supported at all, especially in the past, where the Nouveau driver would recognize the card even though it didn't actually support that specific card, load, and then crash the gpu entirely to the point where the system would lock up or appear to lock up, leaving a stuck keyboard and black screen.  This particular problem is where the Nouveau driver got its bad reputation.  The only solution in this situation is to boot the system in a mode that partially or fully disables the Nouveau driver and then install a more appropriate driver for the card.
Some features likely will never be supported by nouveau. For all features, you must use the proprietary driver. See https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/FeatureMatrix.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software)

And is there also a performance difference for the supported functionnalities?

Depends on how you look at it.  One of the things that is unsupported is using the gpu to accelerate graphics calculations...  So does it support unaccelerated graphics?  Yes.  Does the proprietary driver make unaccelerated grpahics faster?  who cares when you have accelerated graphics?

I am not sure I understood correctly but it seems you say that Nouveau drivers do NOT support accelerated graphics, which I do 100% care about, as it makes them almost unusable.

Some features likely will never be supported by nouveau.  For all features, you must use the proprietary driver.  See https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/FeatureMatrix.html  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software)
